# Отступы в блоке DIV

Tags: css, html

Здравствуйте уважаемые специалисты, будьте добры помогите решить проблему. Есть блок `div` отображаемый как `display: table` и в нём еще два `div-а` отображаемые как столбцы display: table-cell, вопрос: почему когда я применяю `margin-top: 100px` к содержимому первого столбца он автоматически применяется и ко второму? Вот упрощенная ситуация: https://jsfiddle.net/ayjj02yy/32/ Как сделать чтобы не смещался?

```html
<div style="display: table; border: 1px solid;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; height: 250px;">
     <div style="margin-top:100px;">1 колонка</div>
  </div> | 
  <div style="display: table-cell;">2 колонка (почему смещается?)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отображение элементов `display: table;`, `display: table-cell;` и аналогичные им создают по сути [эмуляцию таблицы](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/29-display-table-anti-hero). Соответственно, и поведение таблиц.

Псевдо-таблица:

```
<div style="display: table;"></div>
```

Псевдо-ячейка:

```
<div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
```

В таком случае, браузер создаст дополнительные анонимные элементы строки и таблицы, которыми Вы не сможете ими управлять.

При табличном поведении, если задать высоту ячейки таблицы или значение высоты содержимого этой ячейки будет больше высоты строки, поменяется и сама высота строки.

Для построения блочной модели, рекомендую использовать [flexbox](https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/).

Для примера:

```css
#container {
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex; /*отображает контейнер как блочный элемент*/
justify-content: flex-start;
}
#container>div.cell{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container>div.cell>div{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"><div>1</div></div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, подскажите а для что даёт `display: -webkit-flex;` ?

Comment: Это префикс браузера. Подробнее https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-browser-prefixes

Comment: благодарю, а почему в нашем коде префикс только для хрома, почему нет `moz`, `ms` ?

Comment: Это для примера

Comment: а если я его не укажу, простой атрибут `display: flex;` не выполнится в хроме?

Comment: Выполнится. Данное свойство уже поддерживается браузерами